# working with cookies without sending to the browser and document headers

Tags: cookies, browser, server-side, client-side

I want to develop an idea using cookies on the server side but I am afraid that I should not rely on cookies behavior as the following references say that cookies are client-side and browser-based objects:

[Microsoft:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321(v=vs.85).aspx)

> HTTP cookies provide the server with a mechanism to store and retrieve
>   state information on the **client application's system**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> An HTTP cookie (also called web cookie, Internet cookie, browser
>   cookie, or simply cookie) is a small piece of data sent from a website
>   and stored on the **user's computer** by the user's web browser while the
>   user is browsing

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_cookies.asp):

> A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file
>   that the server embeds on the **user's computer**

[Mozila.org:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

> An HTTP cookie (web cookie, browser cookie) is a small piece of data
>   that a server sends to the **user's web browser**. The browser may store
>   it and send it back with the next request to the same server.

However, On the server side, I tested that changing the value of cookies works fine without the role of the browser. I want to make sure that kind of using cookies is a  standard way so I rely on it to generate some temporary data [I asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955572/can-browser-handle-a-disposable-js-file) before.

```
<%
Response.Cookies("a")="test <br>"
response.write request.cookies("a")

Response.Cookies("a")="test1 <br>"
response.write request.cookies("a")

Response.Cookies("a")="test2 <br>"
response.write request.cookies("a")

Response.Cookies("a").Expires = DateAdd("d",-1,Now())
%>
```

**result:**

```
test
test1
test2
```

And there are no cookies with name **"a"** in headers of the page and no object is created on the visitor browser. It seems that the cookie was created and killed on the server and the browser knows nothing about it!

My question is that if the definitions of top mentioned references are wrong? Do they miss some details about the server side characteristics of cookies? What are the problems if I use cookies as temporary variables on the server side?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as "server-side cookie". Confusion is that the server asks for the browser to store cookies. This [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922145/what-is-the-difference-between-server-side-cookie-and-client-side-cookie) gives a good example:

> Browser request example:
>
> `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.example.com`
>
> Example answer from the server:
>
> `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-type: text/html
>   Set-Cookie: foo=10
>   Set-Cookie: bar=20; Expires=Fri, 30 Sep 2011 11:48:00 GMT
>   ... rest of the response`
>
> Here two cookies foo=10 and bar=20 are stored on the browser. The
>   second one will expire on 30 September. In each subsequent request the
>   browser will send the cookies back to the server.
>
> `GET /spec.html HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.example.com
>   Cookie: foo=10; bar=20
>   Accept: */*`

What you may be looking for is a **user session** in the server-side (also referenced in that same thread). JEE implementation usually rely on the jsessionid cookie to identify user's data in the server side. Take a look at [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5451/dwsessn.html) about user session:

> The term user session refers to a series of user application
>   interactions that are tracked **by the server**. Sessions are used for
>   maintaining user specific state, including persistent objects (like
>   handles to EJB components or database result sets) and authenticated
>   user identities, among many interactions. For example, a session could
>   be used to track a validated user login followed by a series of
>   directed activities for a particular user.

Comment: Thank you for references. What is difference between cookie and session in my example code? Is it OK to use cookies instead of session or variables?

Comment: Session and cookie usually work together, as my jsessionid example. Is your code in ASP? Check [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp) to understand the difference. To store something in the session, you should do like Session("key") = "value".